# (retain, nonatomic) and (nonatomic, retain) any difference?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

What is the difference between (retain, nonatomic) and (nonatomic, retain) in code such as this:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) YellowViewController *yellowViewController;
```

?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no difference -- the order of property attribute specifiers is not important.

Answer (score 4):

I've seen both ways used - there's no difference.